# C# Linq to SQL Query between 2 Dates nos getting results

Tags: c#

I'm building a complex search query using Textboxes, Comboboxes and DateTimePicker.

For the Textbox and Combobox, the queries are working fine, but when add a datetimepicker for query between 2 dates, I'm getting nothing...

Using EF6 with LINQ...

So, my class to store data:

```
public class Projetos
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Conc { get; set; } //Combobox
        public string Ent { get; set; } //Combobox
        public string Def { get; set; } //Textbox
        public DateTime DataR { get; set; }
    }
```

The first query and return results:

```
public IEnumerable<Proj> LoadProj()
    {
        var ctx = new JEntities();
        var query = (from p in ctx.tblProjs.AsQueryable()
                     join c in ctx.tblConcs on p.ConcID equals c.ConcID
                     join e in ctx.tblEnts on p.EntID equals e.EntID
                     select new Proj
                     {
                         ID = p.ProjID,
                         Conc = c.NameConc,
                         Ent = e.NameEnt,
                         Def = p.DefP,
                         DataR = p.DataR
                     });
        // The combination of these 3 controls works fine!           
        if (TxtDefP.TextLength > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.DefP.Contains(TxtDefP.Text));
        }
        if(CmbCon.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            string SelectedValue = CmbConc.GetItemText(CmbConc.SelectedItem);
            query = query.Where(s => s.Conc == SelectedValue);
        }
        if(CmbEnt.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            string SelectedValue = CmbEnt.GetItemText(CmbEnt.SelectedItem);
            query = query.Where(s => s.Ent == SelectedValue);
        }

        //When filtering between these 2 dates, I get no results

        if (DataRFrom.Checked && DataRTo.Checked)
        {
            DateTime begin = DataRFrom.Value.Date;
            DateTime end = DataRTo.Value.Date;
            query = query.Where(s => s.DataR > begin && s.DataR < end);
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

In the SQL, I have dates like this... Perhaps the Date format in SQL are messing up all this???

[image]

My questions is, why can't I get any results between 2018-06-01 and 2018-06-06 since records with this date range are in Database?

Thanks.

Comment: what are the values of `DataRFrom` and `DataRTo`? what RDBMS are you using (Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL...)?

Comment: DataRFrom is a DateTimePicker with String Format yyyy-MM-dd. I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: Trace the database and look at the SQL

Comment: What is result when you select DataRFrom = 2018-06-20 and DataRTo=2018-06-30?

Comment: The result is an empty table since my query result will fill an datagridview. If no results from query, the datagridview will be empty!

Answer (score 0):

Date property is missing:

query = query.Where(s => s.DataR.Date > begin && s.DataR.Date < end);

Comment: When using DataR.Date I get an error... "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities".

Comment: There is no `Date` property on DateTimePicker

Comment: Crap, my bad, you are indeed correct there is no property.